# conda virtualenv name is missing in shell prompt?

Tags: python, zsh, conda

In a new machine, I install anaconda, and create a virtualenv using conda. But when I activate the virtualenv, the name is not displayed in shell prompt ? But I am using zsh in mac. Anyone know what's may be wrong here ? Thanks

Here's what I do (python2.7 is a virtualenv that I created before)

```
➜  ~ source activate python2.7
➜  ~
```

I expect it be

```
➜ (python2.7) ~
```

Comment: This will depend on the shell prompt you are using (and that in turn on the OS you are using) and how you have configured your command line prompt to be displayed.  Are you on Linux/OSX/Windows, if Linux are you using Bash, ZSH or something else.  If ZSH the later are you using any plugins to prettify your prompt.

Comment: What do you see when you do `conda create -n test_env` followed by `conda activate test_env`? In my bash shell, that displays `(test_env)` in the prompt.

Comment: @slackline I use zsh

Comment: @zjffdu : and what plugin / prompt style are you using under ZSH?  Have you checked that it supports showing the current active virtualenv?

Comment: @slackline Do you know who to check what plugins I am using ?

Comment: oh, I check .zshrc, I only use git plugin

Comment: Please edit your question to include exactly the commands you run, exactly what the result is, and what result you expect. It might also help to demonstrate that you really are in your env. E.g., show something like `which python` before and after activation.

Comment: The recommended way to activate changed in conda v4.4 ([see release notes](https://conda.io/docs/release-notes.html#recommended-change-to-enable-conda-in-your-shell)) so you should update your practice. Also, are you using `virtualenv` or `conda` to manage your virtual environment? You seem to be treating the terms "virtualenv" and "virtual environment" as interchangeable when they are not and so it's very unclear.  I'm guessing the `virtualenv` tag should be removed. The common idiom among conda users is to call a virtual environment simply an "env".

Answer (score 0):

As you've indicated you are not using any ZSH plugins other than a git one you may wish to consider using a customised prompt to ensure you get the expected behaviour.  Many people use [Oh-my-ZSH](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) which has a range of additional prompt customisations available, many of which go beyond just indicating what virtual environment you are running.